# How can I read a numbers from a specifically formatted stringstream?

Tags: c++, string, file, stream

I have a huge file that contains geometric objects with their coordinates next to them. 
the format is like this:
rectangle,(42,25),(68,25),(68,70),(42,70)

I want to read each number alone and store it in array as I later process this data to find the shapes areas and perimeters.

```
string line = ""; // A string for reading lines from the text file
ifstream readFile("Input_Points.txt"); // Opening the input file

string name = ""; // A string to store the type of the shape

while(getline(readFile,line))  { 
    // Loop through the file lines
    stringstream iss(line); // Instantiate stringstream with the current line just read
    getline(iss, name, ','); // Parse token until the first comma and store it in name
    Shape * obj = gobj[name]; //Fetch the corresponding object from map using name
    if ( obj != NULL )  { 
        // If it can find an object with name index
        obj = obj->clone(iss); // Clone an object of the same type               
        cout << name << ":" << obj->area() << ":" << obj->perimeter() << "\n";  // Calculate area and print it
        delete (obj); // delete the object 
    } 
    else 
        cout << "Undefined Object Identifier\n"; // Cannot find object type in map
}
```

and the two functions were I handle the data

```
void Square::initialize (stringstream & ss) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        sscanf(ss,",(%lf,%lf)", points[i].X, points[i].Y);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        LineLength[i] = points[(i + 1)%2] - points[i];
    }
}

Shape * Square::clone (stringstream & ss) { //can be done with templates 
    Square * square = new Square();
    square->initialize(ss);
    return square;
}
```

the sscanf doesn't do what I want here and I have done a lot of searching and couldn't find something similar that performs what I want to do on string streams.

Comment: Regular expressions?

Comment: Of course "sscanf doesn't do what" you want. Can't do much of anything, if it doesn't even compile. sscanf is a C library function that doesn't know anything about C++ streams. Whichever C++ book gave you an example of using `sscanf` together with a `std::stringstream` -- this book is no good, need to find a better book.

Comment: This wasn't from a book, I placed here sscanf as an example to show that I want to read from stringstreams like sscanf does.

Comment: Hint [parsing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing). You need to *parse* the strings you read.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis what do you mean ?

Comment: `std::stringstream` is fundamentally different from `sscanf`. You can't make it work "like sscanf does". It doesn't work this way. Any good C++ book should have plenty of examples of how to use formatted extraction operators. Please review the many examples in your C++ book, and if you have any ***specific*** questions, they can be asked on stackoverflow.com

Comment: @JesperJuhl I know but how can I parse it so that I take each number alone. This was my question

Comment: @SamVarshavchik a specific question would be: how can I read from a stringstream formatted like this so that I take a number at a time

Comment: Michael means [regular expressions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Comment: Rather than putting that forth-coming revised question in a comment, [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55619929/edit).

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion:

1. Replace all the extraneous characters by space characters in the string.
   `(`, `)`, and `,` can all be replaced by space.
2. Extract the numbers from the simplified string.

---

In the first step, `"rectangle,(42,25),(68,25),(68,70),(42,70)"` can be transformed to `"rectangle  42 25   68 25   68 70   42 70 "`.

Reading the numbers from such a string is straight forward.

Comment: I was just about to post this. Doing this before creating the stringstream really does simplify everything.

Comment: I thought of this, but wouldn't be more powerful if I could just tell the program to get the data in between the two brackets and separated by a comma?

Comment: I just like simpler code. The more code I write means more bugs.

Comment: @MinaAshraf, by more powerful, if you mean "very geeky", then yes. I don't see it more powerful otherwise.

Comment: totally agree, but for me to learn a new technique, can you suggest a way that extracts what is in between the brackets? A lot of people are working on the project and if I edited the file, it may destroy all the code they wrote. That's why I don't think I can edit the file

Comment: Who said you have to edit the file? Nobody said that you need to edit the file.

Comment: @MinaAshraf Modify the string after reading it but before you try to parse it. You don't need to modify the file.